# convert protobuff class as model and store its value using realm

Tags: android, realm

I am generating protobuf class using [Squareup Wire protobuf](https://github.com/square/wire) libary

here is my proto file

```
syntax = "proto2";

package squareup.dinosaurs;

option java_package = "com.squareup.dinosaurs";


message Dinosaur {
  // Common name of this dinosaur, like "Stegosaurus".
  optional string name = 1;

  // URLs with images of this dinosaur.
  repeated string picture_urls = 2;

}
```

and here is my auto generated code

```
// Code generated by Wire protocol buffer compiler, do not edit.
// Source file: dinosaur/dinosaur.proto at 8:1
package com.squareup.dinosaurs;

import com.squareup.wire.FieldEncoding;
import com.squareup.wire.Message;
import com.squareup.wire.ProtoAdapter;
import com.squareup.wire.ProtoReader;
import com.squareup.wire.ProtoWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import okio.ByteString;

public final class Dinosaur extends Message<Dinosaur, Dinosaur.Builder> {
  public static final ProtoAdapter<Dinosaur> ADAPTER = new ProtoAdapter<Dinosaur>(FieldEncoding.LENGTH_DELIMITED, Dinosaur.class) {
    @Override
    public int encodedSize(Dinosaur value) {
      return (value.name != null ? ProtoAdapter.STRING.encodedSizeWithTag(1, value.name) : 0)
          + ProtoAdapter.STRING.asRepeated().encodedSizeWithTag(2, value.picture_urls)
          + value.unknownFields().size();
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(ProtoWriter writer, Dinosaur value) throws IOException {
      if (value.name != null) ProtoAdapter.STRING.encodeWithTag(writer, 1, value.name);
      if (value.picture_urls != null) ProtoAdapter.STRING.asRepeated().encodeWithTag(writer, 2, value.picture_urls);
      writer.writeBytes(value.unknownFields());
    }

    @Override
    public Dinosaur decode(ProtoReader reader) throws IOException {
      Builder builder = new Builder();
      long token = reader.beginMessage();
      for (int tag; (tag = reader.nextTag()) != -1;) {
        switch (tag) {
          case 1: builder.name(ProtoAdapter.STRING.decode(reader)); break;
          case 2: builder.picture_urls.add(ProtoAdapter.STRING.decode(reader)); break;
          default: {
            FieldEncoding fieldEncoding = reader.peekFieldEncoding();
            Object value = fieldEncoding.rawProtoAdapter().decode(reader);
            builder.addUnknownField(tag, fieldEncoding, value);
          }
        }
      }
      reader.endMessage(token);
      return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public Dinosaur redact(Dinosaur value) {
      Builder builder = value.newBuilder();
      builder.clearUnknownFields();
      return builder.build();
    }
  };

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

  public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "";

  /**
   * Common name of this dinosaur, like "Stegosaurus".
   */
  public final String name;

  /**
   * URLs with images of this dinosaur.
   */
  public final List<String> picture_urls;

  public Dinosaur(String name, List<String> picture_urls) {
    this(name, picture_urls, ByteString.EMPTY);
  }

  public Dinosaur(String name, List<String> picture_urls, ByteString unknownFields) {
    super(unknownFields);
    this.name = name;
    this.picture_urls = immutableCopyOf("picture_urls", picture_urls);
  }

  @Override
  public Builder newBuilder() {
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    builder.name = name;
    builder.picture_urls = copyOf("picture_urls", picture_urls);
    builder.addUnknownFields(unknownFields());
    return builder;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof Dinosaur)) return false;
    Dinosaur o = (Dinosaur) other;
    return equals(unknownFields(), o.unknownFields())
        && equals(name, o.name)
        && equals(picture_urls, o.picture_urls);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = super.hashCode;
    if (result == 0) {
      result = unknownFields().hashCode();
      result = result * 37 + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
      result = result * 37 + (picture_urls != null ? picture_urls.hashCode() : 1);
      super.hashCode = result;
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (name != null) builder.append(", name=").append(name);
    if (picture_urls != null) builder.append(", picture_urls=").append(picture_urls);
    return builder.replace(0, 2, "Dinosaur{").append('}').toString();
  }

  public static final class Builder extends com.squareup.wire.Message.Builder<Dinosaur, Builder> {
    public String name;

    public List<String> picture_urls;

    public Builder() {
      picture_urls = newMutableList();
    }

    /**
     * Common name of this dinosaur, like "Stegosaurus".
     */
    public Builder name(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * URLs with images of this dinosaur.
     */
    public Builder picture_urls(List<String> picture_urls) {
      checkElementsNotNull(picture_urls);
      this.picture_urls = picture_urls;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Dinosaur build() {
      return new Dinosaur(name, picture_urls, buildUnknownFields());
    }
  }
}
```

now the issue is i want to directly store the value of `Dinosaur` into the database using [Realm in android](https://realm.io/). i want `Dinosaur` class to act as a model.
but the problem is `Dinosaur` class is declared as final so i cant even derive it.

So is there any design pattern or way that exists to reuse or convert `Dinosaur` class into model?

Comment: Did you find a solution? What alternative did you go for?

Comment: Nope buddy , i had to use the two different model as its not  good to alter the schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the Wire `Dinosaur` with Realm as Wire also require you to extend the `Message` class, while Realm require you to extend `RealmObject`.

If you want to combine the two you can create a `RealmDinosaur` class that accept the wire Dinosaur. Something like this:

```
public class RealmDinosaur extends RealmObject {

  private String name;
  private RealmList<RealmString> pictureUrls;

  public RealmDinosaur(Dinosaur dino) {
    // Fill Realm fields. Note that Realm doesn't support Lists 
    // with primitive strings yet.
    // See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primitive-lists
  }

  // getter and setters

}

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(new RealmDinosaur(wireDinosaur));
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Good example of what I meant when I said "create another set of objects...that you only use with Realm"

Comment: You could say the same for Wire. It is not uncommon to have objects representing data transfer and business rule objects. Combining them is nice for less code, but also means you are mixing two concerns that really shouldn't be mixed and can cause problems (like this one).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

For me, this is one of several show-stoppers for wide adoption of Realm.
The developers of Realm don't seem to have considered real-world use-cases such as yours, where your data objects already inherit from something.

They also seem don't seem to get Android's threading requirements.

If you really want to use Realm, I think that you'll have to create another set of objects, likely in another package, that you only use with Realm. Then, you'd have to copy your data from your 'real' objects into the Realm objects.

Personally, for anything non-trivial, I'd either use the built-in SQLite, or find another database that better meets your needs.

Comment: Do you mind saying what the other show-stoppers are?

Comment: The threading model. Realm requires that you interact with objects only on the thread on which they were queried. They seem to think that it's ok to do database access on the UI thread because it's objectively "pretty fast". 

If you want to query for objects on a background thread and use them on the UI thread, you have to copy the data from the Realm object to another instance that isn't associated with Realm.

Comment: if i go with the SQLite even then i need to copy protobuf object right

Comment: Note that Realm got async queries and transactions some months ago: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries, but I agree there are still cases where the threading constraints can cause problems.

Comment: ""If you want to query for objects on a background thread and use them on the UI thread, you have to copy the data"" --- Wrong, in that case you use `realm.where(Blah.class).findAllAsync()` on the UI thread and add a change listener to the returned results